# how to update the particular column on table2 when update is occured at table1 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I have two different DB's and both DB's have primary testbed table but not exactly all columns are same. I have mentioned sample case for both tables.

**So, My requirement is:**

Whenever the column "PrimaryTestbed" is updated in db1.primary_testbed table after updation of that, column "PrimaryTestinfo" in db2.primary_testbed the table also needs to be updated on exact matches?

This is what, I tried:-

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER PRIMARY_TESTBED_AFTER_UPDATE 
AFTER UPDATE ON db1.primary_testbed 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE db2.primary_testbed 
SET PrimaryTestinfo = NEW.PrimaryTestbed 
# how to put where clause here? 
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

**Below are my tables: -**

**1) db1.primary_testbed**

```
*************************************************************************************
|Branch      | Model   |  Tool   | Protocol  | Ratio | PrimaryTestbed| HostName     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-A     | MN100   |  tool1  |    IO     |  0    |  arr-1        |  xxxxxxx     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-B     | LK4000  |  tool2  |   CSID1   |  2    |  arr-230      |  yyyyyyy     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-A.1.0 | JP5000  |  tool2  |    IO     |  1    |  arr-500      |  xxxxxxx     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-B.1.0 | MN1000  |  tool1  |    IO     |  5    |  arr-220      |  xxxxxxx     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-C     | DQ3000  |  tool1  |   CSID1   |  0    |  arr-100      |  xxxxxxx     |
*************************************************************************************
|  rel-A.2.0 | MN100   |  tool2  |   CSID1   |  10   |  arr-600      |  zzzzzzz     |
*************************************************************************************
```

**2) db2.primary_testbed**

```
**********************************************************************
| Release    | Model   |  Tool   | Protocol  | Ratio | PrimaryTestinfo|
**********************************************************************
|  rel-A     | MN100   |  tool1  |    IO     |  0    |  arr-1        |
**********************************************************************
|  rel-B     | LK4000  |  tool2  |   CSID1   |  2    |  arr-230      |
**********************************************************************
|  rel-A.1.0 | JP5000  |  tool2  |    IO     |  1    |  arr-500      |
**********************************************************************
|  rel-B.1.0 | MN1000  |  tool1  |    IO     |  5    |  arr-220      |
**********************************************************************
|  rel-C     | DQ3000  |  tool1  |   CSID1   |  0    |  arr-100      |
**********************************************************************
|  rel-A.2.0 | MN100   |  tool2  |   CSID1   |  10   |  arr-600      | 
**********************************************************************
```

Prompt assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any issues in using Triggers?

Comment: Yes, I started to write trigger but in between, I stuck up with some syntax problem. Where I got stuck is, between BEGIN and END Statement.

Comment: @V_instincts can you post what you have tried?

Comment: This is what, I tried:                                                                                                                   DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER PRIMARY_TESTBED_AFTER_UPDATE
 AFTER UPDATE ON db1.primary_testbed
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE db2.primary_testbed
        SET PrimaryTestinfo = NEW.PrimaryTestbed
        # how to put where clause here?
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos, I have added in questions itself. Thank you. awaiting your response.

Comment: 'needs to be updated on exact matches' - what are they exactly?

Comment: If update occurred for this matches (branch = "rel-A" and model =  "MN100"  tool ="tool1"  and protocol = "IO"  and deduperatio = 0 ) in db1.primary_testbed table. For same matches update has to occur in db2.primary_testbed.   Am i cleared you question? @P.Salmon

Comment: I don't quite see the problem the syntax for the where statement is pretty normal except you refer to the new. value ( as you have done in the set statement)

Comment: @P.Salmon, I have tried the where clause, can you please check this.                DELIMITER $$
 CREATE TRIGGER reports.PRIMARY_TESTBED_AFTER_UPDATE 
 AFTER UPDATE ON db1.primary_testbed
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE db2.primary_testbed
        SET primary_testbed = NEW.PrimaryTestbed
        WHERE branch = OLD.`Release` AND 
        model_code = OLD.Model AND Protocol = OLD.Protocol AND tool = OLD.Tool
        AND dedupratio = OLD.DedupeRatio;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Guys any help on this?